# Download images saved on Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, download, boto3

I need to download images that are uploaded by https://webapp.spypoint.com. These images are saved in Amazon S3. The url for this image is something like this as: https://s3.amazonaws.com/spypoint/1111/2222/3333/img.jpg

I have id and password to log in https://webapp.spypoint.com. My goal is to download images from Amazon S3 directly using boto3.

I researched about it and all information was about downloading images from Amazon S3 bucket owned by myself. For my case, the Amazon S3 storage/bucket is owned by https://webapp.spypoint.com.

Comment: Any reason for wanting to use boto3 vs just using requests and plain HTTP?

Comment: If your method can download images from Amazon s3 using your method, it should be fine.  However, I also need to get a list of subfolders under https://s3.amazonaws.com/spypoint/1111/2222/.  Can I do that using your method?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a public bucket, then this will work:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests

url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/spypoint/1111/2222/3333/img.jpg"
Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url).content))
```

But you cannot 'explore' the bucket this way, e.g. getting a listing, etc. You need to go through the S3 API for that, e.g. using `boto3`, as you say. And it sounds like it's not a public bucket.

If it's their bucket, then to get to it via the S3 API (e.g. with `boto3`), they will have to allow you to access it. Or maybe they have their own API?

Comment: Yes. for this reason I need to use boto3.  Also when I used your code I got errors as: OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001BCF0C16830>

Comment: That's because the link you posted isn't an image, at least not a public one. Use the URL of an accessible image and it works. I would ask Spypoint what they advise.

Comment: Its not what I wanted.